# How to get look up field id in controller

Tags: apex, visualforce

[image]

Here active property html email is command link and i referred controller,
When user click that link means it needs to get that id of look up field and information of that id.
in that controller i need to get this look up field value when user select values

Answer (score 3):

Quite simple actually, just use lookup's field id as the binding in the VF page. E.g. let's say you have VF page on which you are editing YourObject__c, and that object has a lookup field named Lookup_Field__c. Your VF page would probably look something like this:

```
<apex:page standardController="YourObject__c" extensions="YourObjExtensionController">

    <apex:form id="form">
        <apex:pageMessages />

        <apex:pageBlock id="pageBlock" mode="edit">

            <apex:pageBlockButtons id="pageBlockButtons" location="bottom">
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" id="submitButton" action="{!save}"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" id="cancelButton" action="{!cancel}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>

            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
                <apex:inputField value="{!MyObject.Lookup_Field__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!MyObject.Some_Other_Field__c}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>

        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

...while your controller would resemble something like this:

```
public with sharing class YourObjExtensionController {

    public YourObject__c MyObject { get; set; }

    public YourObjExtensionController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        MyObject = (YourObject__c)controller.getRecord();
    }

    public PageReference save() {

        // do something with MyObject.Lookup_Field__c
        // save impl here (insert/upsert)

        return new PageReference('/' + MyObject.Id);
    }
}
```

It would, however, help if you could provide more details on your situation - e.g. editing existing records, inserting new ones, etc.

Comment: thanks for ur answer but i edited the question please check once

Comment: nice answer dino